# Tic tac toe game with a dynamic board Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a Jquery game which has a user defined table/board eg 3x3, 4x4. I have made the board, but due to the dynamic nature of the table cells I am unable to access them: to change the value inside them and to keep a track of their indexes. Is there a way to find the cell indexes and find the cell being clicked on, to change its value?

```js
   <!-- ========================================== Jquery starts here====================================================== -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        var RowStartParam = "<tr>";
        var RowEndParam = "</tr>";
        var TdStartEndParam = "<td></td>"

        var MakeBoard = function () {

            var BoardSize = $('#enterNum').val();
            //alert(BoardSize);
            var BoardRow = RowStartParam;

            for (var i = 0; i < BoardSize; i++) {
                BoardRow += TdStartEndParam;
            }



            BoardRow += RowEndParam;

            //alert(BoardRow);
            for (var j = 0; j < BoardSize; j++) {
                $("#board > tbody").append(BoardRow);
            }


        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#enterBtn").click(function () {


                MakeBoard();
            });






        });
    </script>
```

```css
 <style>
        .text-centre {
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
        }
        
        table {
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            border-left: 1px solid;
            border-right: 1px solid;
        }
        
        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid;
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <!-- ============================================================board size input======================================== -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Size for board" alt="Board size" id="enterNum" />
    <button class="btn" id="enterBtn" type="button">Enter</button>

    <div class="text-centre">

        <table id="board">
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Showing some code would be helpful.

Comment: not hard to get a row index and a cell index using `index()`. Really not clear what your problem is

Comment: Firstly, I am trying to find the clicked cell change its value, Secondly call a function which will use the indexes of the cells to figure out if a player has won.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code a bit but it's basically the same. To answer your question, there is a delegated onclick event added that will return the current row and cell being clicked. Hope that helps.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEjopy?editors=001

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#enterBtn').click(function() {
    makeBoard();
  });

  $(this).on('click', 'td', function() {

    var parent = $(this).parent().index()+1;
    var position = $(this).index()+1;

    alert('row = ' + parent + ', cell = ' + position);
  });

});

function makeBoard() {

  var rowstart = '<tr>';
  var rowend = '</tr>';
  var cell = '<td></td>';
  var boardsize = $('#enterNum').val();
  var boardrow = rowstart;

  for (var i = 0; i < boardsize; i++) {
    boardrow += cell;
  }

  boardrow += rowend;

  for (var c = 0; c < boardsize; c++) { 
    $('#board > tbody').append(boardrow);
  }
}
```

I think it is good practice to camelCase functions but keep variables lowercase so it's easier to make a distinction. But it's a personal preference in the end of course.

Comment: I found a simpler approach to yours, just playing around. But your input was very helpful. My approach was to make  $("tbody td").click(function () {}) inside the MakeBoard() function, to check the if a cell had been clicked. Then made a WinChecker() which is called inside the $("tbody td").click(function () {}).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for following up. Much appreciated.